# cloud.google.com go storage library giving undefined: storage.BucketIamConfiguration,storage.ProjectsHmacKeysService

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using cloud.google.com/go/storage (origin/master branch) for one of my project, In the program logic it's calling this function: **storage.SignedURL**

It was working fine like a week ago, and now it's giving the following issue (in between like I updated the branch) :

../../../cloud.google.com/go/storage/bucket.go:1021:28: undefined: storage.BucketIamConfiguration
../../../cloud.google.com/go/storage/hmac.go:93:7: undefined: storage.ProjectsHmacKeysService

The go version, platform, and source location| version 10.13.6 macOs Sierra :

go version go1.12.7 darwin/amd64

Fetch URL: https://code.googlesource.com/gocloud
Push  URL: https://code.googlesource.com/gocloud

on go mod it shows :

cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.1.0

I tried several things, but unable to find the cause?

Comment: It Solved  By Doing this : After doing this it worked :-), (I found a similar issue posted by someone here : https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/ )See Go get command on my command (terminal) line :
London:storage esumit$ go get -u cloud.google.com/go/storage
go get: warning: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=auto in GOPATH/src;
ignoring go.mod;
see 'go help modules'
London:storage esumit$

Comment: Hi @Sumit Arora,
good work finding the solution! Can you post your comment as an answer and accept it (https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Sure I have done that :-)

Answer (score 1):

It Solved By Doing this, Actually found a similar issue posted by someone here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1358

**go get -u cloud.google.com/go/storage**